# Filter out odd (out of common order) rows

Tags: postgresql

Let's assume I have a table with a `counter` column where all new rows has an equal or larger `counter` integer value. For example a proper table could like this:

```
id  | counter
-------------
 1  |       0
 2  |       1
 3  |       3
 4  |       3
 5  |       4
 6  |       7
 7  |      11
 8  |      19
 9  |      19
10  |     120
11  |     124
12  |     133
```

However let's assume some odd rows are inserted that breaks the rule like in this example with 2 *NOT good* rows :

```
id  | counter
-------------
 1  |       0 (first row)
 2  |       1 (larger value, good)
 3  |       3 (larger value, good)
 4  |       3 (same value, good)
 5  |       4 (larger value, good)
 6  |      21 (larger value, it appears to be good at this point, however next values proves this was an actually an error, *NOT good*, should be removed from the result sets)
 7  |      11 (smaller value, it appears to be NOT good at this point, however next values proves this was NOT an error, should NOT be removed from the result sets)
 8  |      19 (larger value, good)
 9  |      19 (same value, good)
10  |     120 (larger value, good)
11  |      64 (smaller value, *NOT good*)
12  |     133 (larger value, good)
```

Would it be possible filter/discard those NOT good rows from result sets?

Comment: There are multiple solutions to this, so it's not clear which solution do you prefer. 1. id in (6,11), 2. id in (6,10), 3. id in (7,8,9,11), 4. id in (7,8,9,10). Do you prefer less rows deleted then smaller counters deleted? Your example would suggest that, but it isn't clear. Even if you define preference there would probably be multiple valid solutions for some data.

Comment: If you inserted by mistake some data and want to find it, it might be possible to figure out which rows are inserted in which order, which can allow you to find the erroneously inserted rows based on hidden `xmin` column. Make a disk-based backup ASAP as the more data is changed on the database the less reliable can the search be.